# Drawing shapes into the Rectangle

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, gdi+

I developing paint application with winform and i have to draw some custom shapes(right arrow, left arrow, trapezoid, rhombus etc) but i dont understand how drawPolygon method drawing wrong coordinates. I have a ShapeFactory class and i create shape by geometricalShape enum. I just add coordinates of shape into the class but it doesnt draw correctly.

GeometricalShape Enum:

```cs
public enum GeometricalShape
    {
        Left_Arrow,
        Right_Arrow,
        Triangle,
        Left_Triangle,
        Right_Triangle,
        Bottom_Triangle,
        Rounded_Rectangle,
        Diamond,
        Pentagon,
        Hexagon,
        Star,
        Six_Pointed_Star,
        Parallelogram,
        Trapezoid,
        Rectangle,
        Circle,
        Cube,
    }
```

ShapeFactory Class:

```cs
public static class ShapeFactory
    {
        private static IShape desiredShape;
        public static IShape GetShapeBase(GeometricalShape shape)
        {
            switch (shape)
            {
                .
                .
                case GeometricalShape.Triangle:
                    desiredShape = new Triangle();
                    break;
                .
                .
            }
            return desiredShape;
        }
    }
```

All shapes uses IShape interface. Some regular shapes uses RegularShapeBase abstract class also.

```cs
public interface IShape
    {
        public void Draw(Graphics graphics, System.Drawing.Rectangle rect, Pen pen);
        public void Fill(Graphics graphics, System.Drawing.Rectangle rect, Brush brush);
    }

public abstract class RegularShapeBase: IShape
    {
        public abstract Point[] GetCoordinates(System.Drawing.Rectangle rect);

        public void Draw(Graphics graphics, System.Drawing.Rectangle rect, Pen pen)
        {
            graphics.DrawPolygon(pen, GetCoordinates(rect));
        }
        public void Fill(Graphics graphics, System.Drawing.Rectangle rect, Brush brush)
        {
            graphics.FillPolygon(brush, GetCoordinates(rect));
        }
    }
```

Then, triangle class with its own coordinates:

```cs
public class Triangle : RegularShapeBase
    {
        public override Point[] GetCoordinates(System.Drawing.Rectangle rect)
        {
            return new Point[]
            {
                new Point(rect.X,rect.Height), //Left bottom
                new Point(Math.Abs(rect.Width / 2),rect.Y),//Top center
                new Point(rect.Width,rect.Height),//Right bottom
            };
        }
    }
```

[Expected Drawing and Actual Drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JC77f.png)

I expected that codes must be work successfully but it didnt work unfortunately. I think the problem is X and Y coordinates of current shape (Triangle in this problem) aren't inside rectangle. That X and Y coordinates started from left of picturebox instead of left of Rectangle. That is the main problem. How can i solve this problem and create general answer? Because i have many classes related custom shapes like Rounded Rectangle, Hexagon etc.

Comment: You forgot to add the current Location of the rectangular area to the calculation, e.g., `new Point(rect.X + rect.Width, rect.Height)` or `new Point(rect.Right, rect.Height)` -- `Math.Abs()` is not needed, `Width` (a dimension) cannot be negative -- You could (with some changes) make the Factory generic.

Comment: I tried after  i select rectangular area on picturebox with mouse but If I make the rectangle normal or inverted, the points go outside the rectangle. I just want to set drawing area as Rectangle. All drawings must be inside in Rectangle. But how can i do, literally idk. I have so many custom shape classes like triangle. I cannot change all positions for just Rectangle. I want to be create general alignment method for all drawing operations.

Comment: I don't know what *make the rectangle normal or inverted* means. Anyway, since it appears you want to draw your shapes inscribed in a rectangular selection, you have to consider the selection's Offset. E.g., in the case of an isosceles triangle, it's then (clock-wise) `new Point(rect.Left, rect.Bottom), new Point(rect.Left + (rect.Width / 2)), rect.Top), new Point(rect.Right, rect.Bottom)` -- The same applies to any other shape.

Comment: Oh, It works. I figured out how to overcome this problem. Thank you.